# "RuntimeError: super-class __init__() of %S was never called" when using self.tr in __init__ call

Tags: python, pyqt, translate

In code over PyQt, when self.tr is used in call to init of the ancestor class,
an error is produced. The call without self.tr works. See below:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui

class cl1(QtGui.QWidget):
  def __init__(self,txt):
    super(cl1,self).__init__()
    self.edit = QtGui.QLineEdit(txt)
    lay = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
    lay.addWidget(self.edit)
    self.setLayout(lay)
    self.show()

class cl2(cl1):
  def __init__(self):
    # This line does not work:
    super(cl2,self).__init__(self.tr("kuku"))
    # If this line is used instead, it works:
    # super(cl2,self).__init__("kuku")

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
w = cl2()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: And what does `self.tr("kuku")` return? Clearly you cannot call `self.tr()` before `QtGui.QWidget.__init__()` has been called, so like the doctor said to the woman that asked how to make it stop hurting if she presses there, "Don't press there".

Comment: Set the text for the `QtGui.QLineEdit()` object on `self.edit()` *after* calling `super(cl2, self).__init__()` with an empty value.

Comment: My question was if it is possible to do all in single call

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As has already been pointed out, you cannot call a method of a base-class before it has been initialized.

One way to work around this issue is to use the static [QApplication.translate](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qcoreapplication.html#translate) method (PyQt does not provide a static `QObject.tr` method):

```
    super(cl2,self).__init__(QtGui.QApplication.translate("cl2", "kuku"))
```